# Unity Firestore , get data convert to string

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to c#, I am trying to save the data I get from firestore into a string and I have searched and tried many different things and cannot seem to get it, any help is much appreciated, Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using System;

public class FirestoreGet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name;
    public string lastName;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start");
        call();
    }

    async void call()
    {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
        DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("Test").Document("Test");
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id);
            Dictionary<string, object> data = snapshot.ToDictionary();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in data)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share any debug logs you have (this should be able to run in the Editor for convenience)? To confirm, is your "Document" named `Test` and is it in a "Collection" named `Test` as well? A screenshot of the Firestore console could also help if it doesn't reveal too much information. Are you doing something like `var dependencyStatus = await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()` as well and waiting for that to return outside of this script?

Comment: yes my debug console returns the data, I am just unsure of how to turn the data it returns into a string

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this right, your data is there and you are logging it. You just need a string in C#. There are a couple of ways to do that.

The simplest would just be to do:

```
var strValue = (string)pair.Value;
```

If the value is not a string, you will get an [`InvalidCastException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=net-5.0) that you'll want to handle (data is coming from the internet, you *always* want to validate it).

To avoid this, you can do something like:

```
if (pair.Value is string) {
    var strValue = (string)pair.Value;
}
```

You can also use the `as` keyword, which instead of raising an exception will cause the value to go to null:

```
var strValue = pair.Value as string;
```

And finally, you can use the `.ToString()` method in case you have a non-string value in there as well that you want as a string.

```
var strValue = pair.Value.ToString();
```

If you expect `pair.Value` to go to `null` (probably a good idea), you can use null-propagation. Be warned that this *will [not work as expected](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) on any type that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`*, so don't sprinkle this around your codebase.

```
var strValue = pair.Value?.ToString() ?? "null";
```

Later on, if your data becomes more structured, you can use Firestore's [built in serialization capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects). This is how I usually interact with Firestore in my own games:

```
[FirestoreData]
struct MyData {
    // get a string, to answer the question in the post
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    // get an int to demonstrate that it's not string specific
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}
```

```
docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) => {
    var snapshot = task.Result;
    if (snapshot.Exists) {
        var myData = snapshot.ConvertTo<MyData>();
    }
});
```